# Manipulate theme version - hook into wp_get_theme()

Tags: wp-get-theme

I want to alter the version of a theme, returned by `wp_get_theme()`. I checked in the source code, and saw that `wp_get_theme()` returns `new WP_Theme( $stylesheet, $theme_root );` and there is no hook involved in the process...

I then went one step deeper and checked in `class WP_Theme` to find a hook, but from what I've seen there is no useful hook in there either.

So can you give me any insight on how to manipulate the theme version returned by `wp_get_theme()` please

Comment: Why do you want to alter the theme version? Theme versions are baked into the header comments params of a theme.